# google spreadsheet change year then table clears automatically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have question about google spreadsheets.

I have expenses and income table where is all business incomes (from projects) and expenses (salaries/products/licenses).

Is it possible like I have in table year 2020 so it takes from other tables these datas and if I change this year to 2021 it starts over but 2020 is like archived.

Main sheet table:

| Expenses | 2020 |
| --- | --- |
| Salaries | $4000 |

Example I have sheet tab named salaries

| date | name | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12-02-2020 | John Doe | $800 |
| 18-04-2020 | Mary Doe | $800 |
| 20-05-2020 | Steven Doe | $800 |
| 09-08-2020 | Henry Doe | $800 |
| 02-11-2020 | Jane Doe | $800 |
| 12-02-2021 | John Doe | $900 |
| 18-04-2021 | Mary Doe | $900 |
| 20-05-2021 | Steven Doe | $900 |
| 09-08-2021 | Henry Doe | $900 |
| 02-11-2021 | Jane Doe | $900 |

So if I change in my main sheet table `expenses` year to `2021` it should automatically find this year salaries from sheet named `salaries` and sum it up. What would be then `$4500`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

In your main sheet, you can use this formula on cell B2:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(salaries!A2:C,"select sum(C) where year(A)="&B1&" group by year(A)"),2,0)
```

The `QUERY` function pulls the entries on the defined year in cell B1 in main and sum the salaries. The `INDEX` function removes the header row pulled by the previous function.

Sample Data:

[image]

Sample Result:

[image]

References:

[QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)

[Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

[INDEX()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242?hl=en)

Comment: But if he adds more rows so he has to add change formula?

Comment: Edited answer. Range is now A2:C so it will check for all rows with data

Comment: Why your command gived me text salaries but not summed this year salaries? I need only sum not salaries text.

Comment: You can use this on cell B2 instead: ````=INDEX(QUERY(salaries!A2:C,"select sum(C) where year(A)="&B1&" group by year(A)"),2,0)````

Comment: Do you have also possible make example if I want us quarters or half of year sums?